# Reserving specific memory for container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We have a container on docker that can use up to 10Gb of memory during specific times of day. When the container is deployed we specified reservation below so that it it placed on the server with most available physical memory. While this part works it does not prevent other containers to be placed on that server as well, and when the containers starts to use up memory it is impacting other containers.

Is there a ways to permanently reserve memory for specific container?

```
    reservations:
      cpus: "0.25"
      memory: 10000M
```

Comment: Are you using docker swarm or just docker-compose?

Comment: Also which docker-compose version, 2 or 3 ?

Comment: We are using swarm orchestration. Engine Version:  19.03.12
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)